# Django model i18n of content

Tags: python, django, django-models, localization, internationalization

In my design there are some models where I need to store certain fields in different languages. Has it be done before? I saw some Django modules that help do model translations but some of them did not work properly.

Any best practices out there? Below is my code.

My model,

```
class Lookup_I18n(models.Model):
    i18n_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Lookup(models.Model):

    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    value_i18n = models.ForeignKey(Lookup_I18n)
    value = models.Field()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('purpose', 'key'),)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used recently [django_modeltranslation](http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/). It will create extra fields in each table for for translation of a field in a certain language. You can provide the translation through Django admin panel. Here are [some applications](http://blog.muhuk.com/2010/01/06/dynamic-translation-apps-for-django.html) for Django that translate the models. I had to translate just a field in the model and it worked. Choose the application that suits best with your design.